# Oracle SQL Developer 3.0.04 Freezes when viewing table data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, freeze

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer 3.0.04. Trying to connect to a remote DB. Don't have any issues with database connection, it connects.

But when trying to view a selected tables rows a small progress bar within a small dialog box titled "Display Results" appears saying "Waiting for Checking if Object is Editable" and the progress  is stuck. Cannot see any data of the selected table.

I tried to export the schema and data, but it freezed at once. So I closed SQL Developer.
Tried to attempt that again but now cannot even view the tables details.

Used TOAD in another machine and connected using that, no issue then the table listed all the data. Checked on the remote machine using putty and "sqlplus" to connect and the data showed as expected.

So that tells me that something in my local machine is wrong. Cannot connect using SQL Developer. Has anyone out there faced similar issue? please any idea on this matter?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try connecting to any other database, remote and local ? Does this happen with every database or only one connection? Perhaps something is wrong with that installation folder of SQL Developer, perhaps something got corrupt while it was stuck. Perhaps try to download the latest version of SQL Developer from [this link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html) and try again.